# xdotool key ignored by Firefox while working on other windows

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, xdotool

I'm on **Ubuntu 20**, **Firefox 84.0 (64-bit)**.

I've been trying to use **xbindkeys** and **xdotool** to create custom keyboard shortcuts for special characters like '→' or '«' (in brief, I hate compose key and ctrl+shift+u methods, I have always prefered windowish style shortcuts with alt key and I decided to achieve this on my own).

After a lot of time it works pretty well... **Except for Firefox !**

#### Say I want alt+1 to type '«'

Here is my **.xbindkeysrc.scm** (I use the guile config file rather than the standard .xbindkeysrc file because I have other more complex shortcuts dealing with mouse scroll for volume for example, but it really does the same thing):

```
(xbindkey '(alt KP_1) "xset r off; xdotool keyup --window 0 KP_1 key --clearmodifiers --window 0 U00AB; xset r on")
```

(See https://askubuntu.com/questions/455762/xbindkeys-wont-work-properly for more details on why `xset r off` and `keyup` parts)

**This works perfectly fine on my terminal, on a gedit window, on a LibreOffice writer doc...** Only Firefox won't type the right sign. Actually, it doesn't type any sign, after a short delay it acts as if I had only pressed the alt key, which shows the menu (File, Edit, ...) on the top of the Firefox window.

#### Any idea ? :)

#### EDIT

- The problem is not specific to the use of alt key (which is already mapped to some shortcuts in Firefox): changing to control key doesn't change much (does nothing, instead of showing the menu like the alt key)
- It is actually possible to send xdotool events to Firefox. I got Firefox window's id (here, 37749011), and then tried manually on the terminal: `xdotool windowfocus --sync 37749011 key --clearmodifiers --window 0 U00AB` which correctly typed '«'. But still does not work when I try keyboard shortcut

Comment: Full code available here: https://github.com/mrtgenet/xbindkeys-guile-mouse-altkeys-and-more

Comment: +1.  Same problem here. Some things work, such as "xdotool click 2" to middle-click. Others such as "xdotool key ctrl+Page_Down" don't work, but work in other non-Firefox windows such as Konsole.